# Как определить координаты клика для SendMouseClickEvent?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Типо есть метод `SendMouseClickEvent` (кликнуть куда-то в браузере), но нужно указать координаты клика. Где их узнать? Вообще, можно как-то указать элемент по которому кликать на сайте или что-то типо такого?

Comment: Очень редко где приходится использовать клик по координатам. Практически во всех случаях достаточно сделать `.click()` по элементу.

Comment: Напишите это в ответ, чтобы я смог ответить.